# create a 3D line from 3D points in Arcgis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, 3d, points-to-line

I have a large amount of 3D points that represent several (separate) linear elements. This means that these points partly have the similar/(same) x,y - coordinates and differ only in the height (z) (like power lines). But the single points have no relation to each other, i.e. the left point knows nothing about its right point or other points. Using the *Near function* I could only find the nearest point, but not the point on the other side of the point. The *function Generate Near Table* generates the information about both points, but unfortunately only works in 2D, so that superimposed line-like elements will mix in the 2D plane. 
My goal now is to create a single line for each line-like element. In the beginning I tried to do this with the *point2Line function*, but the line was quite crisscross, so I tried to correct this with a small *buffer*. The next step would be to generate a centerline of this polygon, but ArcGIS does not seem to support the generation of a centerline from closed polygons.

Is there a way to create a polyline from 3D points with ArcGIS? A 2D line would be one approach, because then I could work it with this [tutorial](https://community.esri.com/groups/3d-mapping/blog/2018/10/26/how-to-create-3d-lines-from-2d-points-with-an-elevation-attribute) from next.

Comment: Are the points in a particular order? There is a points to polyline tool https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003s000000 which will join the points in order of appearance or sort by a given field. There is collapse dual line to centreline but trust me this tool is more pain than it's worth for the data you have - it doesn't like fluctuating buffers much.

Comment: Unfortunately, they have no order or index that they can dictate. The points are a subset of a LIDAR record.

Comment: Try minimum spanning tree.